# include or project setting in msvc for uint8_t and similar types?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

When I create a new msvc project and try using the type uint8_t I get the following compile error:

```
error C2065: 'uint8_t' : undeclared identifier
```

Is there a project setting or predefined include that I can use?  I'd prefer not to typedef values explicitly.

Comment: Could it be you have a previous error during compile ? And that error cause this error ? Give us all the errors you got during compilation. Which project did you create with VC, console ?

Comment: Also post your code might help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to [include `<stdint.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#stdint.h) (or `<cstdint>`), which is [not available prior to VS2k10](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99131/c99-header-stdint-h-missing) as far as I can tell.

If you're using an older version of `cl` you can search for an open source implementation that meets your licensing requirements, or if none exist you'll have to supply the `typedef`s yourself.

Comment: This: but please only use <cstdint> if it is C++ that you are writing. The standard only mentions <cstdint>.

Comment: @111111: agreed, granted I have no clue what he's writing as he tagged it as C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Boost library have some definitions for this. But it's only for C++.